# MATLAB ActiveX vs. Python Win32COM

Tags: python, matlab, powerpoint, activex, win32com

I am trying to migrate a program I created in Python to MATLAB. This application uses win32COM to write/read to/from Excel and PowerPoint and I assumed the ActiveX commands would be very similar/identical because it is based on VBA. If someone could shed light on this and help with the following error I would appreciate it!!

So I have a Python code which works

```
PPT_App = win32com.client.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")
Presentation = PPT_App.Presentations.Add()
Cover_Slide = Presentation.Slides.Add(1,12)
```

However when I convert that to MATLAB;

```
PPT_App = actxserver('PowerPoint.Application');
Presentation = PPT_App.Presentations.Add();
Cover_Slide = Presentation.Slides.Add(1,12);
```

it gives me this error on line 3 defining 'Cover_Slide';

```
Undefined function 'Add' for input arguments of type 'Interface.91493469_5A91_11CF_8700_00AA0060263B'.
```

Anyone have an idea why this is happening or where I could find info on ActiveX differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're not based on VBA; rather, it's the other way around, and anything you can do in VBA, you can do with ActiveX (so that in particular, what you can do with VBA, you can also do with MATLAB), but the methods and properties exposed by the COM object are a *superset* of those (so that `win32com` gets you a bit further).

What you're seeing here is that, for whatever reason, the `Slides` COM object has a method called `Add` that is not available through ActiveX. What you do have, though, is an almost synonymous method called [`AddSlide`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/slides-addslide-method-powerpoint) which you can use in MATLAB. The only difference between the two is in the second parameter; `Add` takes a value in the [`PpSlideLayout` enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/ppslidelayout-enumeration-powerpoint) (with the value of 12 corresponding to a blank slide), where `AddSlide` expects a [`CustomLayout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/customlayout-object-powerpoint), which you can create through [`Presentation.SlideMaster`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/presentation-slidemaster-property-powerpoint). Concretely, since in my case a "blank slide" happens to be the seventh available layout (when counted in the "New slide" dropdown), what you can do is

```
Presentation = PPT_App.Presentations.Add();
Layout = Presentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts.Item(7)
Presentation.Slides.AddSlide(1, Layout)
```

In general, refer to the VBA documentation to see what is possible through MATLAB. In my experience, the discrepancy between this and the general COM object is limited.

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation!!

Comment: You're welcome. Perhaps interestingly, the discrepancy means that `Add` works in VBA, but only `AddSlide` gets auto-completion.

Comment: Hi, maybe you can help me with something else? I cannot find much documentation on this subject. I am trying to retrieve a sheet by name, such as 'Summary = wb.Sheets('Status color chart')' but I am getting an error that index exceeds matrix dimensions. I see how to get the sheet by an index, but I am having trouble getting it by name!

Comment: @SHK: In MATLAB, you mean? If so, you probably just need to do `wb.Sheets.Item('Status color chart')`.

Comment: `win32com` generates default methods for these objects (so that `Sheets._Default` and `Sheets.__call__` ends up translating to `Item`); you might find it instructive to investigate the source code auto-generated by `win32com` by `makepy.py` (or by `xl = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')`).